# How to use AppBarLayout's lift-on-scroll with ViewPager + RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity layout that's like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then, in the activity, the viewpager is populated with three fragments. Each of these fragments has a layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
        <RecyclerView />
        <Other views />
    </FrameLayout>
    <Other views />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, in other views where `RecyclerView` is not used for the content, the lift-on-scroll works just fine (for instance, when using `NestedScrollView` instead of `RecyclerView`). However, with `RecyclerView` it doesn't work. How should it be configured to make it work?

Comment: Hi @manabreak, I have almost the same configuration (and the same issue) !
Did you find a solution since then ?

Answer (score -1):

Add this on appbar:

```
app:liftOnScroll="true"
```